# How to check if a set is a subset of another set in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count, relational-division

[image]

Text to DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe1(
    Ingredient varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO Recipe1(Ingredient) VALUES('Flour'),('Egg'),('Sugar');
CREATE TABLE Recipe2(
    Ingredient varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO Recipe2(Ingredient) VALUES('Egg'),('Sugar');
```

I want to check if Recipe 2 is a subset of Recipe 1, and I want SQL to return a boolean value, how can I do that?
I found out that ORACLE supports a function called SUBSET:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/big-data-discovery-cloud/BDDEQ/reql_sets_subset.htm

But I can't find an equivalent for SQL Server or even MySQL. And I hope to get an answer for SQL Server.

Our instructor used this code:
`"Recipe 1" CONTAINS("Recipe 2")` but it **doesn't work**.
Also, I'm not using or planning to use Full-text search so I need a workaround.

Comment: Are Recipe1 and Recipe2 tables?

Comment: Yes, they are tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach uses a `left join` and `count()`s:

```
select (count(*) = count(r2.id)) as is_subset
from recipe1 r1
left join recipe2 r2 on t1.id = t.id
```

That would work in databases that somehow support booleans (such as MySQL). A more portable approach uses `case` in the outer query:

```
select case when count(*) = count(r2.id) then 1 else 0 end as is_subset
from recipe1 r1
left join recipe2 r2 on t1.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Left join should work as well

```
Select count(*) ct 
from Recipe2 r2 
left join Recipe1 r1 on r2.Ingredient = r1.Ingredient
where r1.Ingredient is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the recipe above are tables, then the following query will yield a count of 0 if `Recipe2` is a subset of `Recipe1`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(SELECT * FROM Recipe2
 EXCEPT
 SELECT * FROM Recipe1) AS x
```

See: [Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It gives me a syntax error on the last parenthesis, I don't understand why.

Comment: Ohh I see now, it must have a name otherwise returns an error (referring to `AS x`).

Comment: This is SQL-Server syntax (TSQL). I see that you also have a MySQL tag. MYSQL does not have an equivalent. See: [How to do MINUS/EXCEPT and INTERSECT in MySQL](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/multiple-table-select/minus-except.php) for an alternative solution for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you can use `EXISTS` and aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Recipe1 r1 WHERE r1.col1 = r2.col2)) AS is_subset
FROM Recipe2 r2
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM Recipe2 r2 
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Recipe1 r1 WHERE r1.col1 = r2.col2)
       ) is_subset
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a1b9df05e70b26acf15b7a59a2ce6cae).

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server:

You can use Join and Case when like the below.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(R1.C1)=COUNT(R2.C1) THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' END AS IS_SUBSET
FROM (VALUES ('Flour'),('Egg'),('Sugar'))R1(C1)
RIGHT JOIN (VALUES ('Egg'),('Sugar'))R2(C1)
ON R1.C1=R2.C1
```

SQL Fiddle demo link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/107092/0